# How to handle Ctrl + Enter with TextBox when AcceptsReturn is true?

Tags: c#, textbox, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

In my UWP application, I want my `TextBox` to be able to go to new line by pressing down the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key but I also need to trigger an action when  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> are pressed.

The issue is, I can't seem to find a way to *prevent the text to go to the next line* when I press down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Here is the code I have tried.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

**In the constructor**

```
TextBox1.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(TextBox1_KeyDown), true);
```

**Handler**

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
    if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a custom class that inherits from `TextBox` and override its `OnKeyDown` method where you have full control of firing the `base.OnKeyDown` method to prevent from adding a new line.

```
class CTRLEnterTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.